# SQL join with where and limit

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to:

```
- Select 10 random jobs 
- Join the default jobs location name
- Join the default jobs sector name
```

For each joining table I have added `_default` if the job has more than one location for example.

I have the following database structure. 
[image]

The problem I am having is that this query is returning the same jobs more than once.

```
SELECT j.job_id, j.job_name, j.job_uri, j.job_image1, s.section_name as section
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN job_sectors js ON j.job_id = js.job_id
LEFT JOIN sectors s ON s.sector_id = js.sector_id
WHERE j.job_featured = '1'
AND j.job_status = 'ENABLED'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It is not quite clear how this `_default` can be used. Where exactly is it stored?

Comment: Both job_locations and job_sectors have a column with _default that can be used to set the default IF there is more than one. E.g a job has more than one location but the main job location is et to default.

Comment: Oops, overlooked both `job_sector_default` and `job_location_default`, I'm sorry. So, `job_sector_default` references a sector that is default for the same row's `job_id` and similarly for location, is that right? Do default sectors reside in `job_sectors` on their own rows too or are they only stored in the `_default` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select 10 jobs in a subquery.  If one job has  multiple sectors, you would end up with more than 10 rows (but still 10 jobs.)

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        from    jobs
        where   jobs.job_featured = '1'
                and jobs.status = 'ENABLED'
        order by
                rand()
        limit 10
        ) as j
left join
        job_sectors js
on      js.job_id = j.job_id
left join
        sectors s
on      s.sector_id = js.sector_id
```